# How to properly render SVG in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

Hi Have the following code in our react native application:

```
import { SvgCssUri } from 'react-native-svg';

<SvgCssUri style={styles.osIcon} uri={'https://mon.zappiehost.com/images/os/' + props.data.icon} />
```

I have even tried to use simple `SvgUri` (instead of `SvgCssUri`)

But the image still load with out some of the content (Blacks colors):

[image: What React native Renders the image like]
[image: What it should look like]

Also here is the original SVG image used: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/librenms/librenms/master/html/images/os/proxmox.svg

Comment: @RobertLongson I added a link to the original SVG image that seems to be rendering incorrectly https://raw.githubusercontent.com/librenms/librenms/master/html/images/os/proxmox.svg

Comment: The path that doesn't display has no fill attribute. It should default to black but perhaps there's a bug and it doesn't. You could try giving the patch an explict fill of black or #000000

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the blacks were missing due to the fact that React Native SVG didnt do auto fill.

adding `fill={'black'}` is what was needed into the `<SvgUri>` tag

Comment: you should report that as a bug to the project.